# What is the best way to check a user's permissions while they are browsing through your website?

Tags: asp.net, security, validation, authentication, permissions

Im fairly new to asp.net and am having a hard time finding information about this topic.

I am building a website which will allow users to upload videos. If the videos, for example, are inappropriate or off topic, I can suspend their account so the next time they sign in, they will be redirected to a "Your account has been suspended" page. What I'm trying to figure out is whats the best way to handle the following situation: I suspend a user's account AFTER they have just signed in. So they have already passed validation during the sign in process. I basically would like the user to be redirected to that "Your account has been suspended" page after the next action they perform. Besides checking the database on every postback (which seems a bit inefficient), what would be the best way to handle this?

Please let me know if you need more information or a better example.

Thank you any help

Comment: Not at all familiar with asp.net, so I have no idea if this recommendation is applicable, but I'd just purge all active session data for the user when you suspend them. That will effectively log them out on their next page load.

Comment: I would just check the database on each postback. I think the inefficiency is negligible compared with the time it takes to do a postback.

Comment: If you want to perform the check on every request, an HTTP module is probably the simplest option: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996

Comment: (David Brunow) - So far, that seems like the way to go. (Richard) - I don't know anything about HTTP Modules so I will have to education my self on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. Create a new `BasePage` and inherit your aspx pages from this class instead of System.Web.UI.Page.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
   {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
         // I assume you already get the user's profile
         if (User.IsSuspended)
           Response.Redirect("/SuspendedPage.aspx");

         base.OnInit(e);     
      }    
   }
}
```

**Updated:**

There are a lot of ways to store a value through out the application life cycle. Here is one of them.

```
// Global.asax.cs
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && 
      HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Items["User"] = 
         GetUserByUsername(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to how I check if the user is logged in. I use a master page which all users pages are based off of and I check in the page load event. If User.MemberID = 0 then Response.Redirect("sign-in.aspx"). Using your example, how and when does the User.IsSuspended property get filled?

Comment: Im not worried about where to store the info once the user has authenticated. Its notifying the user that they have been suspended after they have authenticated successfully. For example, user signs in, account is 'Active'. User searches for videos to watch,(user account is still 'Active'). Then I change their account status to 'Suspended'. Then the user searches for more videos to watch but is redirected to a page saying "Your account has been suspended." I might just have check their status in the DB on every postback otherwise the suspend wont take affect until they sign out then back in.

Comment: Application_AuthenticateRequest is what you need. It is fired on every page request.